# Is it possible to execute Jenkins build on Bitbucket PR updates?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, webhooks

As title says, is there any way to setup Jenkins to run tests every time a PR is opened or the PR is updated (new commit is pushed)?

When a PR is opened, there is no issue, I can use webhooks or some of the plugins on Jenkins. However I cant find a way of dealing with new commits pushed to the PR to rerun the build on Jenkins.

Has anyone achieved this with Bitbucket server and Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it seems a new webhook event has been added starting from Bitbucket 7.0, called "Source branch updated". That can trigger an event every time a new commit is pushed to an open PR.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-10279?focusedCommentId=2367993&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2367993

For bitbucket < 7.0 there seems to be no way to achieve this. Workarounds seems to be, manually changing the PR description or adding some comment on the PR to trigger some of the other webhook events.